# How to evaluate the following (Laplace Transform)

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that the Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$ on $[0,\infty)$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
f^*(\theta)=\int^\infty_0e^{-\theta t}f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}

But if I only have $f^*(\theta)=\dfrac{3+10\theta}{24\theta^2+22\theta+3}$, how to evaluate $f(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

Use partial fractions to write

$$
f^*{\theta} = \frac{4}{7 (6 \theta +1)}+\frac{9}{7 (4 \theta +3)}
$$

And now apply the fact that if $g(t)= e^{-a t}$, then

$$
g^*(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta + a}
$$

To find

$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{84} e^{-3 t/4} \left(8 e^{7 t/12}+27\right)
$$

Comment: I will try it later. Thanks for your help!